# expected primary expression before object c++

Tags: c++

here is my code

```
#include "Square.h"
#include "tools.hpp"

ostream&
Square :: print(ostream& s)
{
  return s << "Square [" << row << " " << column << "]" << endl;
}

ostream&
SqState :: print(ostream& sq)
{

    return sq << "value: " << sq_value;
}
void testSquare();
void testSqState();
int main()
{
    banner();

    testSquare();
    testSqState();
    bye();

}

void testSqState()
{
   SqState sq('-', 4, 0);
   sq.print(ostream s); // << Error occurs here
}

void testSquare()
{
    Square s(4, 0);
    s.print(ostream st);  // << Error occurs here
}
```

The statements between the **..**, there were the error occured.
saying that expected primary - expression s 
and         expected primary - expression st

and the square.h had class Square and SqState.

please help me where is the actuall problem is

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't mix function delaration style and function call style? No wonder the compiler is confused. `**`

Comment: Try `print(s) / print(st)` after creating s/st, `s.print(ostream st);` is a broken function declaration.

Comment: `(ostream s)` looks pretty wrong here!

Comment: He didn't escape the astericks in the post so it's bolded periods, I'd edit it but I'm on mobile and I don't want to just change that.

Comment: Same problem here :) try forward ticks, ````, for code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this code:

> ```
> SqState sq('-', 4, 0);
> sq.print(ostream s);
> ```

You can note that `SqState` has a method named `print()`, that is defined here:

> ```
> ostream&
> SqState :: print(ostream& sq)
> {
>
>     return sq << "value: " << sq_value;
> }
> ```

So, the parameter to this `print()` method is a *reference* (`&`) to an instance of `ostream` (actually, `std::ostream`).
You should provide that instance at the call site, and an option is `std::cout` to print text on the standard console output:

```
sq.print(std::cout);
```

Similarly, for the other code in the `testSquare()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to write something like

```
void testSqState() {
    SqState sq('-', 4, 0);
    sq.print(std::cout);
}

void testSquare() {
    Square s(4, 0);
    s.print(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: great! it worked.. i understood the concept.. thanks for helping

Comment: @nandu Glad to help. So you might consider accepting or at least upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
**sq.print(ostream s);**
**s.print(ostream st);**
```

You don't need to put ostream there, assuming s and st are already defined.